# How can I save the state of python code?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, code-generation

```
def function:
    x=100

var1=type("Myclass",(),{"fucntion":function})

print(var1)
```

The `type()` function will generate a class of name `Myclass` and now I can call it from a object but now I want to save the state of the program.To simply put `Myclass` is generated when type() function runs and I want somehow when I again run the program `Myclass` should already be declared without running type() function.Its like a code that changes itself and saves itself and when again launched runs from the last saved state.

Comment: you should investigate [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Comment: if you want to do something like that you should better be prepared for hell, have a nice debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look into pickling. To save a variable:

```
import pickle
def function():
    x=100

var1=type("Myclass",(),{"fucntion":function})
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
pickle.dump(var1,outfile)
outfile.close()
print(var1)
```

To get the variable:

```
infile = open(filename,'rb')
Myclass = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
```

Comment: How does pickling save the calling context?  I don't think you can examine the call stack, and if you can't return that, you can't stop/restart an arbitrary computation.  You can insist the computation state be saved at place where the call stack content is known, but that makes it much harder to stop/restore because it isn't easy to force that known call stack.

Comment: Pickling is saving Myclass to a file, and after the program is run once, it can be loaded from a file.

Comment: You didn't answer the question.

Comment: Sorry.  I meant, you didn't the question I posed in my comment.